# How does a JApplet Form communication with Servlet?

Tags: java, swing, servlets, applet, japplet

I'm working on a JApplet form to create lesson plans. 
Administrator only can edit lesson plan ( add, edit, delete ). 
I used JApplet Form in netbeans, and I added Table control.

Function ADD:
Administrator can select for example 2 cells and click button "Add lesson", then the add form will be visible.
How can I make it so that two cells will link together in one?
It's the same with delete lesson from table. How do I delete an entire row?

The administrator needs to somehow log in and after the Servlet authenticates the user he can save the lessons (or delete or modify) server-side. Is there a standard way to handle communication between an Applet and a Servlet?

Comment: It is usually better to ask just one question at a time. I edited the question to more clearly focus on what I think you need, but we still have two questions combined into one.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the first part "how can I make it so that two cells will link together?" on easy solution is with JPanel.

Rather than adding two text fields to your form, add a JPanel and then place the two text fields within the JPanel. We can now remove or add this JPanel to the form programmatically. Going further, we could write another class that extends JPanel that includes these two text fields along with whatever additional functionality we need with them.